# Android: NullpointerException at vibrate

Tags: android

I am using the following code , but its giving the nullpointer exception at vibrate.

```
public Server(DroidGap gap, WebView view)    //constructor
        {
            mAppView = view;
            mGap = gap;
        }


    public Server(Context context)            //constructor
        {
            mcontext=context;

        }

public void run()  //run method

        {

                    try {

                        InetAddress serveradd =  InetAddress.getByName(serveraddress);
                        } 
                     catch (UnknownHostException e1) 
                        {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                        } 


                    DatagramPacket packet=new DatagramPacket(buf,buf.length);

                    try
                        {
                            c.socket.receive(packet);

                            dat=new String(packet.getData());

                            if(dat!=null)
                                {

                                ((Vibrator)mGap.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(800);

                                cordovaExample.activity.sendJavascript("displayreciever('"+dat+"')");


                                }

                            Log.d("UDP", "s: ReceivedJI: '" + new String(packet.getData()) + "'");

                          }                  //end of try block



                     catch (IOException e) 

                           {

                                e.printStackTrace();

                           }       
                                 //end of catch block






                }  //end of run method
```

I am getting nullpointer Exception at the followingline

```
((Vibrator)mGap.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(800);
```

I am not able to find out the reason

Any help will be appreciated,

Comment: Did u add vibrator permission in manifest file?

Comment: yes there is permission.I tried by putting the code of vibration in different method then its working but when I called that method from the run method or when I place that code in the run method then its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mGap seems to be null

You should initialize this variable, with your code, we cannot give more help...

EDIT:

please tell me the output of:

```
 Log.d("UDP", "Is this null? " + mGap);
 Log.d("UDP", "Is this null? " + mGap.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE));
 Log.d("UDP", "Is this null? " + ((Vibrator)mGap.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE)));
```

just before the crash line:

```
((Vibrator)mGap.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(800);
```

Comment: thnx for replying I will check for that and will reply if it works or not

Comment: actually I have already initialize mgap..i will add more code in it

Comment: its giving null for mGap..you are right mate mGap is null :-) thnx